# Why does scp get stalled? How do I resolve it?

Tags: 10.04, scp

When I attempted to copy a file (of size, ) over the network using scp I get a error `<file> stalled`
Why does this happen? How do I resolve it?

Comment: I like [rclone](https://rclone.org/) for this; I've never had any problems with it.

Comment: I canceled and restarted the scp command and the problem went away for me

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This happens because `scp` is trying to grab as much bandwidth as possible, and any delay (by a firewall, etc.) can stall it. Limiting the bandwidth (with -l option) will fix it.

For example, you might want to limit the bandwidth to 1 MB/s (= 8192 Kbits/s):

```
 scp -l 8192 <file> <destination>
```

Source: [http://www.aixmind.com/?p=1371 - Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140916063024/http://www.aixmind.com/?p=1371)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link to the source. But I think your source says that `-l 8192` means 8192 Kbit/second, and the `-l` might work up to 1 Mbit/second (which seems to be a bit outdated nowadays).

Comment: @elmicha 8192Kb==1MB

Comment: @Eknath Oops, you're right.

Comment: Just to clarify: the example limits scp's bandwidth to 8192 Kbit/second. The source article's author suggests that this number should work fine for connections of upto 1 Mbit/second.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge _8192Kb==1MB_ Not really, 8192 Kbit is 1 **k**iB!

Answer (score 6):

I've managed to solve it by using rsync:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress /tmp/bigfile.txt user@host.com:/tmp/
```

Answer (score 2):

Any chance you're behind a Cisco ASA firewall? If so, turn off "sequence number randomization" and that'll help a lot -- also disable TCP Offload (ethtool -K $INTERFACE tso off gso off gro off) if you're on a Cisco ASA with Broadcom NICs in your server.

Comment: That's genius. Is that change permanent or do I need to put the command somewhere?

Just to be clear, you have to set that on your NIC, not on the cscotun interface.

Answer (score 1):

Given the error message that we received when the scp stalled I suspected that it was the encryption that was failing.
"The authenticity of host 'myserver (10.10.11.12)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:+zkyskXlxVQ0kRorLW26pzprIYbsM4N3hbaDLz1RNpo"
With that in mind I ran "scp -c aes128-ctr /tmp/test.dan/bigfile.src myserver:/tmp/bigfile".   scp WAS successful with the alternate cipher.   Is there an issue with the default cipher blowing a buffer space?

Might try adding "-c " with an alternate cipher and see if it resolves your stall.